# Can Anime.js grid start randomly every time the animation plays?

Tags: javascript, html, anime.js

I want to make Anime Js grid be shown as 3x4 and the animation to start from a random square every time the animation plays, their documentation is not that good to cover those things, and the only pre-built mode is starting from the center

I can fix the grid show as 3x4 by the HTML itself but it could be done in a better way that is better

[check the animation I want to use here from anime.js website](https://animejs.com/documentation/#gridStaggering)

my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="animation">
    <div class="small square el"></div>
    <div class="small square el"></div>
    <div class="small square el"></div>
    <div class="small square el"></div>
    <div class="small square el"></div>
    <div class="small square el"></div>
    <div class="small square el"></div>
    <div class="small square el"></div>
    <div class="small square el"></div>
    <div class="small square el"></div>
    <div class="small square el"></div>
    <div class="small square el"></div>
</div>
```

My javascript is this:

```
anime({
    targets: '.animation .el',
    scale: [
        { value: 0.1, easing: 'easeOutSine', duration: 500 },
        { value: 1, easing: 'easeInOutQuad', duration: 1200 }
    ],
    loop: true,
    delay: anime.stagger(200, { grid: [3, 4], from: 'center' })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the anime js for another project and realized if it set `from` in `delay` part of configuration as random number multiplied by total of the animating element you have it start randomly
the code for this question should look like this:

```js
anime({
    targets: '.animation .el',
    scale: [
        { value: 0.1, easing: 'easeOutSine', duration: 500 },
        { value: 1, easing: 'easeInOutQuad', duration: 1200 }
    ],
    loop: true,
    delay: anime.stagger(200, { grid: [3, 4], from: anime.random(0, 12) })
});
```